# git lfs migrate import --no-rewrite unknown flag --no-rewrite

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I'm trying to fix missing pointers issue using `git lfs migrate import --no-rewrite` first i list all the files that had missing pointers using `git reset --hard`:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec("git reset --hard", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);

            reject(error);
            return;
        }

        const filesWithMissingPointers = Array.from(
            stderr.matchAll(/\t(.*)/g)
        ).map((m) => m[1]);

        resolve(filesWithMissingPointers);
    });
});
```

Then i log the output:

```
console.log(
    `Problem files before lfs migrating: \t\n${problemFilesBefore.join("\t\n")}`
);
```

Output:

```
Problem files before lfs migrating:     
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/Fonts/Localization/Korean/NotoSansCJKkr-Medium.otf  
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/Fonts/Localization/Latin_Cyrillic_Greek/OctoberPro-Black.otf    
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/Fonts/Localization/Latin_Cyrillic_Greek/OctoberPro-HeavyItalic.otf  
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/Fonts/Localization/Persian/NotoNaskhArabicUI-Bold.ttf   
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/Fonts/Localization/Thai/NotoSansThaiUI-CondensedMedium.ttf  
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/Fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf   
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/Fonts/PoetsenOneRegular/TrueType font file/PoetsenOne-Regular 1.ttf 
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/Fonts/Roboto Medium/TrueType font file/roboto-medium.ttf    
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/Fonts/nevis.ttf 
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/LibrariesDesign/BeautifulDissolves/_Examples/_Assets/Textures/ZomBearSpecular.tif   
IdleGame/Assets/Plugins/LibrariesDesign/BeautifulDissolves/_Examples/_Assets/Textures/ZomBunnySpecular.tif
```

I'm then trying to run:

```
execSync(
  `git lfs migrate import --no-rewrite \ -m "AutoCommit Bot: fix missing LFS points ${process.env.CI_PIPELINE_URL}" ${problemFilesBefore.join(" ")} --yes`
);
```

And i encounter:

```
Error: unknown flag: --no-rewrite
```

I'm encountering the same issue locally when running the command in powershell but i do not encounter it when running it in bash. My scripts runs in docker container (linux) with installed git lfs. Since it's Unix it should use bash as default command line so i don't think that the problem lies in the shell.

Note: I run this script as a job on gitlab

Comment: What does `git lfs version` produce?

Comment: @bk2204 git-lfs/2.3.4 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.8.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--no-rewrite` flag isn't available in Git LFS 2.3.4.  Git LFS has a fairly aggressive release process and as such there are a lot of new features added between versions, which usually come out every 3 months.

If you're using Ubuntu 18.04, you'll probably want to upgrade to 20.04, or at least use a newer version.  The Git LFS Project provides additional binaries and packages you can use if you're uncomfortable upgrading your OS.

If you're using Windows for certain things, you should just upgrade your version of Git for Windows.  Git LFS is shipped with Git for Windows, and the easiest way to get a newer version is to upgrade Git.  Installing a newer version by hand is tricky there because it's hard to override the built-in version.